# Does the 90 million cost for the Falcon Heavy include everything?

Tags: spacex, launch, falcon-heavy

SpaceX says that it costs them 90 million each time to launch a Falcon Heavy, does this include fuel? If I where to purchase a Falcon Heavy launch, how much would it cost me to launch it, buying my own launch site or using the one that SpaceX has. I'm trying to get a most accurate number on the cost of me launching my own Falcon Heavy with equipment into space.

It would be great if someone could help me answer these questions.

Comment: So of course the startup cost of building a pad from scratch is not included in the 90 mil. It is perhaps a part of it, amortized over all the launches planned from the pad.  There are a lot of personnel involved whose salaries are paid out of the cost.

Comment: Fuel, rental of the pad from NASA, insurances (including insurance for damaging the pad), a weighted average between refurbishing recovered or building lost stages, salaries for the entire crew for the duration of the operation, and amortization of all of equipment used. Fuel is actually a tiny fraction of that.

Comment: My understanding is that by paying the price to SpaceX, they fulfill their part of the contract which is to get your payload into the desired orbit and providing you with the appropriate assistance, managing the mission. As @SF. said, fuel is almost negligible compared to the total cost. Further, they wouldn't ever operate from another launch site but their own because they need their own facilities, equipment, and personnel.